# Changing static files directory in MVC3 causes 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, filepath, static-content

I'm attempting to set up my own directory structure for serving up static files:

```
\s (statics)
  \c (css)
  \j (js)
  \i (images)
  etc ...
```

The issue is that I'm seeing a 404 for this directory when referencing it.  When I inspect the file path, it is pointing to the correct location `localhost:port/s/c/style.css`, but for some reason it can't find the file.

Is there a way that I can make this path available via my `Web.config`, or possibly through my `Global.asax` file via routes?  I've heard there are performance penalties associated with using routes, so using the `Web.config` - or an alternative solution - is preferred.

Comment: That's not normal. `localhost:port/s/c/style.css` should work assuming thie file exists in this location and that you haven't messed up with some custom routes.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm gonna go ahead and kick myself.  I should've just waited until the morning to look at it... you were right, I was referencing /s/c/style.css, but it was really /s/c/style.min.css.  Thanks again!

Comment: I have posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://localhost:port/s/c/style.css` should work without any problems. It seems that you have specified a wrong filename which is the reason for the 404 error.